# how to bind html select in order by text in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

i have a json string as

```
 json={"0":"-select-","10":"A","5":"B","14":"C"};
```

which is returned from php code in ordered by text A,B,C

i am binding this json string to select box in jquery as

```
$.each(json,function(k,v){
    $('#UserCityRes').append('<option value="'+k+'">'+v+'</option>');
});
```

but it gives select list in order by value as

```
<select name="citylist" id="UserCityRes">
 <option value="0">select</option>
 <option value="5">B</option>
 <option value="10">A</option>
 <option value="14">C</option>
</select>
```

i needed this in order by text as "-select-,A,B,C" order, not value. but $.each function of jquery is appending it in order of value.

please help me in how to sort and display this in order by text( its working fine in mozilla browser , but not in ie and chrome)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If want to preserve the order of items, I would suggest using array/collection like `[{ "key": "0", "value": "-select-"}, { "key": "10", "value": "A"}, { "key": "5", "value": "B"}, { "key": "14", "value": "C"}]`

Comment: $.each(json,function(k,v){            $('#UserCityRes').append('<option value="'+v.key+'">'+v.value+'</option>'); });

Comment: Thanks Arun, i made my json string in your given format and iterate over it as my given code.this works

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to preserve the order of items, I would suggest using array/collection like

```
[{ "key": "0", "value": "-select-"}, { "key": "10", "value": "A"}, { "key": "5", "value": "B"}, { "key": "14", "value": "C"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are unordered sets. You've got two ways - use sorted keys holding reference to both id and value or use arrays - something like

```
{ "values": [
   { "bar": "foobar" },
   { "foo": "foobaz" }
] }
```

You can iterate over the array with a `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)` and have the original order.

For more info take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857666/iterate-over-jquery-json-object-in-original-order).

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific order to the properties in an object. Convert it to an array of objects, then you can sort it, as an array retains the order once sorted:

```
var items = $.map(json, function(v, k){ return { value: k, text: v }; });
items.sort(function(x,y){ return x.text < y.text ? -1 : 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please refer the following code.

```
var values = [];
for(var i in json.message) {
   values.push({ key: i, value: json.message[i] });
}
values.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value.localeCompare(b.value); });
var str = values.map(function (kvp) { return kvp.value; }).join('\n');
```

Thanks,

Siva